# Trying to switch picture sizes, but always get the small one

Tags: html

I try here to switch between 2 images 500 px wide and 1000 depending on the view port width, but no matter what always get a small image

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> tryings </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img srcset="abstract-500w.jpg 500w, abstract-1000w.jpg 1000w"
             sizes="(max-width: 600px) 500px, 
                    (min-width: 601px) 1000px,
                    1000px"
             alt="an abstract picture" 
             width="500" height="333">
    </body>
</html>
```

Seems I'm doing all like in tutorials, can't find what's wrong

Comment: Does it work if you take out the `(min-width: 601px) 1000px,` line, following the example at [MDN:Responsive images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)?

Comment: Yes, but then it loads only the big image event if i narrow the window

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> tryings </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <style>
      /* For width smaller than 400px: */
      body {
        /* background-color: red; */
        background-image: url('image1.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
  
      /* For width 400px and larger: */
      @media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
        body {
          /* background-color: blue; */
          background-image: url('secondimg.jpg');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use the above code to change the image on a different view ports

Comment: Thanks) some of the tags i didn't learn yet, but i got what was the problem